# Windows 8 Sharing charm

Tags: email, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, sharing

i have an application that should provide sharing possibility, so here is my code:

```
DataRequestDeferral deferral = e.Request.GetDeferral();
var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Utils\shareappemail.html");
 var file2 = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("SCLogFile.txt");
 var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
 var rdr = new StreamReader(stream.AsStream());
 var contents = await rdr.ReadToEndAsync();
 DataPackage requestData = e.Request.Data;
 requestData.Properties.Title = "Bla";
 requestData.Properties.Description = "BlablaBla"; // The description is optional.
 requestData.SetHtmlFormat(HtmlFormatHelper.CreateHtmlFormat(contents));
 List<IStorageItem> imageItems = new List<IStorageItem>();
 imageItems.Add(file2);
 requestData.SetStorageItems(imageItems);
 deferral.Complete();
```

On my developer PC this thing works and file is being attached. But on my tablet it doesn't attach the file - why?

**ADDITION!**

This code attaches a file, i comented out this line: //requestData.SetHtmlFormat(HtmlFormatHelper.CreateHtmlFormat(contents));

**This thing drives me crazy! HOW? WHY? And how can i get HTML content + attached file**

```
DataRequestDeferral deferral = e.Request.GetDeferral();
var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Utils\shareappemail.html");
var file2 = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("SCLogFile.txt");
var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
var rdr = new StreamReader(stream.AsStream());
var contents = await rdr.ReadToEndAsync();
DataPackage requestData = e.Request.Data;
requestData.Properties.Title = "Bla";
requestData.Properties.Description = "BlablaBla"; // The description is optional.
//requestData.SetHtmlFormat(HtmlFormatHelper.CreateHtmlFormat(contents));
List<IStorageItem> imageItems = new List<IStorageItem>();
imageItems.Add(file2);
requestData.SetStorageItems(imageItems);
deferral.Complete();
```

Comment: That is your tablet's os? Windows 8, Pro or RT?

Comment: And tablet on Windows 8 Pro shows the same result. But both PC's, running Windows 8 Pro - attach the file

Comment: Did you check the access rights on the file and folder?

Comment: Its a local storage, no rights are needed. Did you see my addition?! It attaches the file, and sets HTML text but not both in one time.